# Getting the first and the last id grouped by the date and the user

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables, `jobs` and `users`

The example structure from `jobs` is

| id | created_at |
| --- | --- |
| 444 | 2022-12-12 08:00:00 |
| 333 | 2022-12-12 09:00:00 |
| 222 | 2022-12-12 10:00:00 |
| 555 | 2022-12-12 07:00:00 |
| 111 | 2022-12-12 12:00:00 |
| 888 | 2022-12-12 08:00:00 |

and users

| id | user_id | job_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 111 |
| 2 | 1 | 222 |
| 3 | 1 | 333 |
| 4 | 1 | 444 |
| 5 | 2 | 555 |
| 6 | 2 | 888 |

I need to get the first and last job id for each day for each user in the same row. So the result should look something like this.

| user_id | date | first_id | last_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-12-12 | 444 | 222 |
| 2 | 2022-12-12 | 555 | 111 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select  distinct u.user_id
       ,date(created_at)                                                                        as date
       ,first_value(j.id) over(partition by user_id, date(created_at) order by created_at)      as first_id
       ,first_value(j.id) over(partition by user_id, date(created_at) order by created_at desc) as last_id
from   jobs j join users u on u.job_id = j.id
```

| user_id | date | first_id | last_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2022-12-12 | 555 | 111 |
| 1 | 2022-12-12 | 444 | 222 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/uLfnEHkA)